# How can I print result of two for loop in one line side by side in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, output

**I want to print two for loop's result in same line side by side**

*The code something  like this, I know this code is not right:*

```
import string

alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
numb = list(range(1, 27, 1))

for i, j in alpha, numb:
    print('{} {}'.format(i, j))
```

The result I want:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) should fix the issue.

```
import string

alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
numb = list(range(1, 27, 1))

for i, j in zip(alpha, numb):
    print('{} {}'.format(i, j))
```

Comment: it works, Thank you :)